# Zend Framework: lastInsertId is returning 0

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am currently learning Zend Framework from a book called "Appress Pro Zend Framework Techniques, Build a Full CMS Project" and I am stuck at a point where after submitting a bug, the page was suppose to redirect to `confirm` action, but this redirection depends on the result thrown by the Model, which saves the bug to the database.

Here is the code of model bug

```
public function createBug($name, $email, $date, $url, $description, $priority, $status) {
    // create a new rows in the bugs table
    $row = $this->createRow();

    // set the row data
    $row->author = $name;
    $row->email = $email;
    $dateObject = new Zend_Date($date);
    $row->date = $dateObject -> get(Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP);
    $row->url = $url;
    $row->description = $description;
    $row->priority = $priority;
    $row->status = $status;

    //Save the new row
    $row->save();

    // now fetch the id of the row you just created and return it
    $id = $this->_db->lastInsertId();
    return $id;
}
```

The records are saved in the database, however the $id is always returning 0, which is causing the redirection to be escaped.

Comment: What happens if you set `$id` to `$row->id` instead of `lastInsertId()`?

Comment: @Mike B, This worked why dont you upload this as an answer?

Comment: It shows problem from today morning. But as you mentioned, I have replaced the code and it is resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting `$id` to `$row->id` instead of `lastInsertId()`.

Most ORM's work along these lines.

```
 $id = $row->id;
```